# ionic 5 cordova run android returns "No Provider" for any of the providers

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

We have been struggling with this issue for the last two days. Usually, the error saying NullInjectorError: No provider for Spherical! is related to the declaration of providers in app.module.ts and home.module.ts (active component).

Here is our app.module.ts :

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from  '@angular/common/http';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { GoogleMaps, Spherical} from "@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx";
import {Device} from "@ionic-native/device/ngx";
import { FirebaseX } from "@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    GoogleMaps,
    Geolocation,
    Spherical,
    Device,
    FirebaseX
    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and here is home.module.ts :

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import {GoogleMaps, Spherical} from "@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx";
import {Geolocation} from "@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx";
import {Device} from "@ionic-native/device/ngx";
import {FirebaseX} from "@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx";


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage],
  providers: [
    GoogleMaps,
    Geolocation,
    Spherical,
    Device,
    FirebaseX
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

On running ionic cordova run android we get this

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(HomePageModule)[Spherical -> Spherical -> Spherical -> Spherical]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Spherical!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(HomePageModule)[Spherical -> Spherical -> Spherical -> Spherical]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Spherical!
    at NullInjector.get (vendor.js:50718)
    at R3Injector.get (vendor.js:50884)
    at R3Injector.get (vendor.js:50884)
    at R3Injector.get (vendor.js:50884)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (vendor.js:64978)
    at R3Injector.get (vendor.js:50884)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (vendor.js:64978)
    at Object.get (vendor.js:64692)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (vendor.js:42979)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (vendor.js:43091)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:1291)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:1245)
    at polyfills.js:1357
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:470)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:68298)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:469)
    at Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:241)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:656)
```

Comment: why are you importing them again in `home.module.ts`?

Comment: Did that to test, usually removed